# Django - passing a parameter from page redirect

Tags: django, redirect, parameters

I just started with Python and Django and want to redirect a user to a home page after successful form-registration with a head-massage changed to "You have successfully registered". 
My code without changing a massage after redirection is:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name = 'index'),
    path('register/', views.register, name = 'register'),
]
```

views.py:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'first_ap/index.html'
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    t_user = 'Hello my friend'
    context = {
        'viva':t_user
    }
    return context

def register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = RegForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save(commit=False)
        new_user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
        new_user.save()
        return redirect('index')
else:
    form = RegForm()
    return render(request, 'first_ap/register.html', {'form': form})
```

In html file I put:

```
<h1>{{ viva }}!</h1>
```

How should I modify a code to change a context after redirection from "Hello my friend" to "You have successfully registered"? I tried several options but they all failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you just save the message in an object variable:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'first_ap/index.html'
    text='Hello my friend'
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        context = {
            'viva':self.text
        }
        return context

  def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            IndexView.text='You have registered'
            new_user = form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = RegForm()
        return render(request, 'first_ap/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer, but it gave me an error - not define self

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! It is the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'first_ap/index.html'
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # request.GET contains the query parameters, check if `first_visit` is 1 or not
        is_first_visit = self.request.GET.get('first_visit', 0) == "1"

        if is_first_visit is False:
            t_user = 'Hello my friend' 
        else:
            t_user = 'You have successfully registered'
        context = {
            'viva': t_user
        }
        return context

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()

            # add a query parameter to indicate user's first visit
            return redirect(reverse('index') + "?first_visit=1")
    else:
        form = RegForm()
        return render(request, 'first_ap/register.html', {'form': form})
```

- Add a query parameter `first_visit` as 1 (random value) in the redirect call after successful registration.
- Access the query parameter using `self.request.GET` dict
- Change the context value based on the value of `first_visit`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it gives me an error:  
 
  Reverse for 'index?first_visit=1' not found. 'index?first_visit=1' is not a valid view 
  function or pattern name

Comment: Reverse for 'index?first_visit=1' not found. 'index?first_visit=1' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Comment: Fixed the code. Just needed to wrap reverse call over `index` in `redirect`